# Nulls in multiple case update in mysql

Tags: mysql

In mysql I'm having table like given below

Yesterday I've learned one lesson which had impacted big production database.

My first requirement was like updating two username a and b to z and y
And second was updating two emails of id 5 and 6 to z.com and y.com

```
# ID, username, mail
1, a, a.com
2, b, b.com
3, c, c.com
4, d, d.com
5, e, e.com
6, f, f.com
7, g, g.com
8, h, h.com
9, i, i.com
10, j, j.com
```

So when I've decide to do both update at the same like this

```
UPDATE test
SET username = CASE
   WHEN username = 'a' THEN 'z'
   WHEN username = 'b' THEN 'y'
   END,
mail = CASE
   WHEN id = 5  THEN 'z.com'
   WHEN id = 6  THEN 'y.com'
   END
```

And I my prod db got affected like this. Lots of null values

```
# ID, username, mail
1, z, 
2, y, 
3, , 
4, , 
5, , z.com
6, , y.com
7, , 
8, , 
9, , 
10, ,
```

Once I realized, I should mentioned the when condition columns in where calsue as well. Like below for example and its worked

```
UPDATE test
SET username = CASE
   WHEN username = 'a' THEN 'z'
   WHEN username = 'b' THEN 'y'
   END,
WHERE username IN ('a','b')
```

But that is for one update. But if do same two update at same time

```
UPDATE test
SET username = CASE
   WHEN username = 'a' THEN 'z'
   WHEN username = 'b' THEN 'y'
   END,
mail = CASE
   WHEN id = 5  THEN 'z.com'
   WHEN id = 6  THEN 'y.com'
   END
WHERE username IN ('a','b') AND id IN(5,6)
```

Nothing gets update.

So I've some questions
1) Why lots of null came..where I've missed the logic
2) Why my new query is doing update in both columns ..?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `else` in `case when` expression like this:

```
UPDATE test
SET 
    username = CASE
        WHEN username = 'a' THEN 'z'
        WHEN username = 'b' THEN 'y'
        ELSE username
    END,
    mail = CASE
        WHEN id = 5  THEN 'z.com'
        WHEN id = 6  THEN 'y.com'
        ELSE mail
    END
    -- ,dateCol = CASE
    --     WHEN username IN ('a', 'b') OR id IN (5, 6) THEN NOW() 
    --     ELSE dateCol
    -- END
```

And in your last `update` query, try to change `and` to `or`:

```
UPDATE test
SET username = CASE
   WHEN username = 'a' THEN 'z'
   WHEN username = 'b' THEN 'y'
   ELSE username
   END,
mail = CASE
   WHEN id = 5  THEN 'z.com'
   WHEN id = 6  THEN 'y.com'
   ELSE mail
   END
-- ,dateCol = now()
WHERE username IN ('a','b') OR id IN (5,6)
```

Comment: `CASE` is an expression, not a clause.

Comment: @sagi Thanks for your catch.

Comment: @JPG...and lets if I would have one more column date. So what would be the whole query so that I could get the current date in front of updated records only...not others ?